# Can the same @Html.ValidationMessageFor used differently based on the criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 textboxes and want to do the validation if the fields are empty then. But, I want to display the message differently based on the conditions.

//Inside my Model

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter Name")]
    public string txtName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address")]
     public string txtAddress { get; set; }
```

//In 1st view, two textboxes appear so the message should be "Please enter Name/Address"

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtName, "", new { @class = "error" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtAddress, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

//In 2nd View, only Address textbox appears, so the message should be "Please enter Address"

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtAddress, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

I do not have an idea how to achieve this.Anyoe has any ideas then please share. Thank you.

Comment: Short answer is no. Create a view model for each view so that you can apply different attributes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I can't do this with single view model. So only way to do this by creating new view model?

Comment: You could add txtAddressTwo to your ViewModel with a different error message, and deal with the two inputs in the HttpPost Action (if you can't have two ViewModels)

Comment: @RickL, This is not what I want. I want to use the same viewmodel attributes twice.

Comment: Ok well, you have one attribute, with one DataAnnotation giving one jQuery validation message in one ViewModel. If you want conditional messages you're probably in to some jQuery when the page loads to change the validation message for one of the attributes. This can be done. I'm still not clear though how you have one ViewModel but two Views, unless one is a Partial.

Comment: @RickL, Can you please provide me sample solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well based on your comments you could do something, but the main principles should really be one "id" per page, and the DataAnnotations in the ViewModel are tied to that one input. Having to work around this strongly suggests that the design of the page(s) should be reviewed.

You could consider:

(i) text inputs (note TextBoxFor and TextBox):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtAddress, new { @class = "some-class" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtAddress, "", new { @class = "error" })
// txtAddressTwo takes the value assigned to txtAddress in the ViewModel:
@Html.TextBox("txtAddressTwo", Model.txtAddress, new { @class = "some-class" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("txtAddressTwo", null, new { @class = "error" })
```

(ii) Set the validation rules for txtAddressTwo using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtAddressTwo").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "xxx Please enter Address xxx"
        }
    });
});
```

(iii) Reconcile values when the form is submitted (not great practice)

```
$(function () {
    $("#your-form-id").on("submit", function () {
        // Work out the appropriate reconciliation using
        var a = $("#txtAddress").val();
        var b = $("#txtAddressTwo").val();
        // For example (or something similar (very hacky))
        if ($("#txtAddress").val() === "") {
            $("#txtAddress").val($("#txtAddressTwo").val());
        }
    });
});
```

I can't help but think that there must be some special reason to have to need to go about it in this way, and I would really suggest revisiting the limitations you have about only one entry in the ViewModel.

Anyway, I hope this helps a little and sets you on the path to a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: if you feel that this question is useful to other future readers on this site then can you please up vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a (quick and dirty) workarround. In the second view, instead of usind @Html.EditorFor(m => m.txtAddress), use plain html with the jquery validation attributes.

Example:

```
 <input name="txtAddress" class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" 
        id="txtAddress" 
        type="text" value="" 
        data-val-required="Please enter Address" data-val="true">
```

Please note the usage of the data-val-required attribute that contains the actual message.

Comment: The validation is not working. In `<script>` tag , I had put `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>`